# Word 2007 add-in : Clone Word.Range

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

**I need to clone Word.Range object**.

I'm trying to create an hyperlink on each word which matches a given string using the following code. But the Hyperlinks.Add() method seems to modify Range value (rng), and so the while loop runs for ever (whereas the loop works well when I comment the Hyperkinks.Add() line).

```
rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
rng.Find.Forward = true;
rng.Find.Text = value;

rng.Find.Execute();
while (rng.Find.Found)
{
    rng.Document.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, rng.Document.Name, CorrespondingBookmark(rng.Text));
    rng.Find.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: you point the problem line in your question but not provide full code for `Hyperlinks.Add`, what are these dots at the end? there could be the issue... do you have correct syntax? ([here for Word-VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837214%28v=office.14%29.aspx))

Comment: The dots are just there to make it easier to understand as its just a traitment made from rng.Text to find on which bookmark the hyperlink should redirect (for instance if rng.Text is 000-01, the corresponding bookmark would be 000_01). But that can't be the issue as range is not modified in this traitment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by modifying the loop : You should not use the Forward option as it seems to bug.

```
rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
rng.Find.Forward = false;
rng.Find.Text = value;

while (rng.Find.Execute())
{
     rng.Document.Hyperlinks.Add(rng, rng.Document.Name, CorrespondingBookmark(rng.Text));
     rng.Find.Execute();
}
```

I don't know why it's working ...